# Does JETSON NANO support RAPIDS?

Tags: nvidia-jetson-nano, rapids

Is it possible to run data science tools like RAPIDS on a JETSON NANO? After some searching, I am still not very clear... also, if it does, will data analysis run faster on it than on a CPU? Any insights will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sadly, the Jetson Nano doesn't support RAPIDS.  The Nano's GPU uses an older architecture GPU, Maxwell, which [RAPIDS does not support (Pascal or better)](https://rapids.ai/start.html).  The TX2, Jetson NX, and the Xaviers, which have a compatible GPU architecture, are the only ones that community members have seen success with.  I know that there or some community members attempting a port of one or two of the RAPIDS libraries to the Nano, but that is a personal effort by them and YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, sadly those alternatives are significantly more expensive.

Comment: you can use the Nano to run models created by the other options or preprocess and stream the data a RAPIDS enabled system.  However, the Nano cannot do RAPIDS ETL.  That may keep costs down, depending on what you are trying to do.